# How can I send (and receive) extremely large floating arrays from Swift to Objective c++ to c++, and then back up to Swift?

Tags: c++, swift, objective-c++

I am a Swift programmer, my objective-c++ and c++ experience are by NO WAY on par with my Swift experience. I have been successful in sending, and receiving, small arrays of floats from Swift -> Objc++ -> c++ (where processing occurs), and then back up to Objc++, and  Swift. We have a large body of work being performed in C++ which we cannot for the moment migrate to Swift for several reasons (one of which c++ is much more efficient at doing this work than Swift).

The work done by the c++ program is on extremely large arrays of floats. At the moment, these arrays of floats are sent and consumed by the c++ program by way of CSV files. We want to do away with these CSV files in order to eliminate the need to read and write on disk. We would like to deal directly with arrays of floats.

The following code works well with small arrays. But, with very large arrays of 300,000+ the program simply crashes on the iOS device because of memory issues, and then on the simulator the below Objective-c++ code uses up to 59 GB!

Can someone explain, and tell me a better approach to sending and receiving large arrays of floats from Swift to Objc++ to c++ and then back up to Swift?

For the moment, I will spare the .h and .hpp code, and only show the Swift, .mm, and .cpp codes.

```swift
SWIFT CODE:
let objcCppWrapper = ObjcCppWrapper()
        let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: floatArray)
        if let cppArraySameSize = objcCppWrapper.cppProcessSwiftArray(pointer, number_elements: Int32(floatArray.count)) {
            let newArraySameSizePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Any> = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: cppArraySameSize)
            let size = Int32(floatArray.count)
            let floatsSameSizeAny : [Any] = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: newArraySameSizePointer, count: Int(size)))
            print("Swift: 'floatsSameSizeAny' size is \(floatsSameSizeAny.count)")
        }
```

```c
OBJECTIVE-C++ CODE:
-(NSArray *) cppProcessSwiftArray:(float [])array number_elements:(int )number_elements{

    //Transform the float array into a vector array
    std::vector<float> arrayVector(number_elements);

    for(int j=0; j < number_elements; j++){
        arrayVector[j] = array[j];
    }

    CppProcess cppProcess;
    std::vector<float>  cppArray = cppProcess.cppProcessSwiftArray(arrayVector);

    //USES WAYYYYYY TOO MUCH MEMORY! UP TO 59 GB ON SIMULATOR, CRASHES TERMINATES IN IOS DEVICE DU TO MEMORY ISSUE.
    NSArray *returnNsArray = [NSArray array];
    for(int j=0; j < cppArray.size(); j++){
        returnNsArray = [returnNsArray arrayByAddingObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:cppArray[j]]];
    }

    return returnNsArray;
}
```

```cpp
C++ CODE:
vector<float> CppProcess::cppProcessSwiftArray(vector<float> arrayOfFloats) {

    cout << "CPP: Received an array is of size " << arrayOfFloats.size() << '\n';

    std::vector<float> returnedSameSizeArray(arrayOfFloats.size());

    //For the moment, only create an arbitrary array of same size and return it...
    for(int j=0; j < arrayOfFloats.size(); j++){
        returnedSameSizeArray[j] = j ;
    }

    return returnedSameSizeArray;
}
```

Comment: Posix or sysv shared memory, assuming Swift and iOS support one of those apis?

Comment: You should be able to just link the various object files together into a single executable; they’re all going to be compiled to the same form of assembly. Then it’s just a matter of calling functions with the array (which is typically a pointer to a contiguous chunk of memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Swift code is a showcase of bad usages of Swift pointers and Arrays.
Your usage of `UnsafeMutablePointer.init(mutating:)` may cause disastrous result including crashing or unexpected changes of variables.

Also in C++ code, why do you pass `vector` by value? You should better use reference to avoid copying.

Anyway, if you do mind memory efficiency, better care about two things:

- Never use `NSArray` to represent an array of a primitive type

  `NSArray` of `NSNumber` consumes ten times or more memory than `[Float]`
- Avoid copying as far as you can

  As you see, copying doubles memory consumption

---

First, rewrite your C++ code. Use pointers instead of `vector` and avoid unneeded copying.

C++ code:

```
void CppProcess::cppProcessSwiftArray(const float *arrayOfFloats, int count, float *outputArray) {
    cout << "CPP: Received an array is of size " << count << '\n';

    //For the moment, only create an arbitrary array of same size and return it...
    for(int j=0; j < count; j++){
        outputArray[j] = j ;
    }
}
```

Pointers can easily be bridged to Swift, so your Objective-C code has very little to do.

Objective-C code:

```
-(void)cppProcessSwiftArray:(const float * _Nonnull)array count:(NSInteger)count output:(float * _Nonnull)outputArray {
    CppProcess cppProcess;
    cppProcess.cppProcessSwiftArray(array, (int)count, outputArray);
}
```

Then you can utilize the feature of bridging Swift Arrays and pointer.

Swift code:

```
        let floatArray: [Float] = ...
        var resultArray: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0, count: floatArray.count)
        let objcCppWrapper = ObjcCppWrapper()
        objcCppWrapper.cppProcessSwiftArray(floatArray, count: floatArray.count, output: &resultArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, it works.

I had also found this 'working' code here. But, your code is more efficient. I think one of the things that was wrong with my code was that NSArray was being copied at every iteration of the loop.

```
NSMutableArray *nsMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 300000];
for (int i=0; i < 300000; i++) {
    [nsMutableArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:cppArray[i]] atIndex:i];
}

NSArray *returnNsArray = [nsMutableArray copy];
return returnNsArray;
```